# How to create a text-replacement script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

What I need is very simple and yet Google has not turned up anything of use. So I'm trying here.

All it needs to do is replace certain pieces of text with others. A completely irrelevant example would be turning "hell" into "heck" and "damn" into "dang".

I would like it to act on whatever document is open, rather than having to come up with some code to target a specific document.

How do I do this? Assume that I know nothing about scripts or coding.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in [autocorrect](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/57859?hl=en) feature should fulfill your needs without the additional need for a script:

> To always correct a specific word's spelling, right-click on the word and select Always correct to [word].